# Implementing automated tool through django based website

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I would like to implement an automated python tool in website with django framework.
I know the directory structure. But in our automation tool there are so many methods. And when we will write views.py other web related functions will come into.

So what will be the best practice to keep those functions to have a better readability?

I can currently think of the following ways:

1. Inside views.py of my app
2. Keeping tool related functions in another .py module and importing them in views.py accordingly.

If any other way please suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd option is more suggested. What you can do is:

- Create `utils.py` in the app folder where your views.py is situated.
- Inside views:

  ```
  from utils import test_tool
  test_tool(x,y)
  ```